# Heuristics for tree decomposition into k shortest paths

Tags: graphs, heuristics

What kind of heuristics are useful in a tree decomposition of a graph to find the k shortest paths from a given source to a vertex?

Moreover, the local shortest paths at each node in a tree are precomputed. Here, the graph is undirected and weighted. I'm interested in finding only simple paths, i.e., no nodes are repeated in a path.

Comment: Is your question what heuristics are there to find a tree decomposition, or what heuristics are there to find the shortest paths given that you have a tree decomposition?

Comment: yah. i suppose to know about heuristics to find the shortest paths given i have a tree decomposition.